# No HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm trying to create a page on my WordPress site using an HTML file. When I enter the code and preview the page, the title and footer are displayed, with the message "No HTML5 canvas!" in between them. I have this line of code in my script, which as far as I understand should be creating the canvas:

```
<canvas id="screen" name="screen" width=480 height=480 class="noselect">No HTML5 canvas!                                 
</canvas>
```

This is my first time working with HTML, apologies if I'm missing something. Any help anyone can provide would be appreciated.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 2):

your code is working fine, here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amdorra/np7hS/) to prove it, the problem might be your browser

```
<canvas id="screen" name="screen" width=480 height=480 class="noselect">No HTML5 canvas!                                 
</canvas>
```

check out [this page](http://caniuse.com/canvas) for a list of browsers that support *html 5 canvas*

Comment: I am using Safari 5.1.9, which according to the chart should be compatible.

Comment: Tried Firefox as well. Same results.

Comment: what version are you using, and please go to the fiddle link and see if it works.

Comment: Firefox 4.0.1, which should also be supported. It works in the fiddle.

Comment: if it works in the fiddle, and not in your code please paste your code so i could try to help.

Answer (score 1):

Contacted WordPress support and it turns out the site simply doesn't support Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not code your html file the way you want with your canvas tag in it, upload it to an external site and then in your WordPress site use an iFrame and set the src to be your html file with the canvas tag? This might be a way around your problem

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
```

Or either try this http://www.learnopengles.com/how-to-embed-webgl-into-a-wordpress-post/